# how to manually process Liquid tags in Jekyll

Tags: html, ruby, markdown, jekyll, liquid

I am creating a Jekyll theme where all user pages that implement the 'indexable' attribute in the front matter are rendered in the main landing page. So I have the 'frontpage layout:

```
---
layout: root
---

{% assign custom_pages = site.pages | where: 'indexable', true | sort: 'priority' | reverse %}

{% include header.html %}

{% for c_page in custom_pages %}
<div class="container {{ c_page.class | default: '' }}" >
    {{ c_page.content }}
</div>
{% endfor %}


{% include footer.html %}
{% include javascripts.html %}
```

A sample page that will be processed:

```
---
layout: page
title: Us
permalink: /us/
indexable: true
priority: 10
class: us-page
---

<div class="row">
    {% for member in site.data.members %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card card-block">
            <img src="{{ member.gravatar }}?s=256" alt="Avatar">
            <h4 class="card-title text-xs-center">{{ member.name }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ member.description | markdownify }}</p>
            <p class="card-text">
                {% for tag in member.expertise_areas %}
                    <span>{{ tag }}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            </p>
            <a href="{{ member.blog }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" >Mi blog</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

However the liquid tags are appearing unprocessed, like the same output  `{% raw %}` would produce. Is there a way through I could do `{{ c_page.content | magic_here }}` in order to manually get rendered those tags?

**EDIT**. Screenshot:
[image]

**EDIT2**

- [Theme repository](https://github.com/sonirico/geekyll)
- [Web implementation](https://github.com/katodia/katodia.com)

Comment: You can markdownify, but you can't liquidify. Your problem is elsewhere but without complete code, it's hard to spot it. Any code repository ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel Yes, although set up an environment might be tedious right now. I have two repos, one for the theme, an another for the web implementation. In the later I have added the gem locally. I am editing the question to link to both anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Well, despite I still don't know whether the issue is in my code, I am posting how I managed to solve it. Basically I created a filter tag called `liquefy`  which has been put in a `.gem` and whose main task is taking a text with markdown or/and liquid syntax as an argument which will be parsed and rendered.

- **Repo**: https://github.com/sonirico/liquefy
- **Gem**: https://rubygems.org/gems/liquefy

Comment: I think you're supposed to use .output instead of .content (source: http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#documents). However, for my situation it didn't work because I was trying to include information from a collection in a post and the posts and pages are rendered prior to the collection. So I used .content with your plugin and it worked perfectly. Thanks!